# Cannot find module 'vscode'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I've been attempting to make use of the `vscode` module for the development of my custom language server, but I've been running into some issues. The following error appears whenever I try to run the server:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
Require stack:
- /Users/garrettc/src/elastic-lsp/vscode-extension-samples/elastic-lsp/server/out/server.js
    at Function._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:934:15)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:779:27
    at Function._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/garrettc/src/elastic-lsp/vscode-extension-samples/elastic-lsp/server/out/server.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:30)
    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/garrettc/src/elastic-lsp/vscode-extension-samples/elastic-lsp/server/out/server.js'
  ]
}
```

I've looked around and seen this error come up several times, but no fix has worked for me. `npm install` within the root, `server` and `client` folders, but nothing has changed.

Comment: The `package.json` files might not contain the needed dependency in the `root`, `server` and `client` folder. I suggest to add it to that `package.json`, where it fits the best and call `npm install`.

Comment: Any update on this? I am seeing the same.